# createStackNavigator Title Issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have the following `createDrawerNavigator` for a portion of my navigation file:

```
const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomePage,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Home"
    }
  },
      Loads: {
    screen: LoadTabs,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Loads"
    }
  },
        LoadsDetails: {
    screen: LoadsDetails,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Load Details"
    }
  },...
```

And then I have the actual `createStackNavigator` set referencing the above:

```
const StackNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  DrawerNavigation: { screen: DrawerNavigation }
}, {
    headerMode: 'float',
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#4C3E54' },
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerLeft: drawerButton(navigation),
      headerRight: cartButton(navigation, screenProps)
    })
  });
```

My problem is that, while everything works, the title never shows up for any of the screens. Am I setting them up incorrectly in the createDrawerNavigator somehow? And if so, what would be the more appropriate way of doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried changing headerMode ? are you getting the navbar render just title missing or nothing at all ?

Comment: @AhsanSohail - The navbar does appear with the left and right icons that I have set, so I know it's at least partially set up right...

Comment: try using headerTitle instead of just title